# OBSOLETE - Code Consultant: Jabber bot to help you work through your coding problems

Tags: app, obsolete, xmpp

### Screenshot / Code Snippet

[image: screenshot]

### About

Have you ever noticed that simple act of describing a problem you can't get past to a co-worker will help you solve the problem, even if they don't say a thing?

The Code Consultant Bot is based on a (possibly apocraphal) story of a software company that gave employees a stuffed bear to talk to about problems they run into. The employees would ask their questions to the bear and work though problems on their own without distracting others. It takes that concept one step farther by giving you an AI instead of a stuffed bear. It's like Clippy, but it asks you leading, helpful questions rather than giving you unhelpful concrete suggestions.

If you're lucky, it may even direct you to potential answers on stackoverflow.com

#### License

Code Consultant is free to use, the code is available under the Apache Public License, 2.0.

#### Download

Nothing to download.  Send an XMPP/Jabber/GTalk invitation to code-consultant@appspot.com.

For more information, see http://code-consultant.appspot.com

#### Platform

XMPP/Jabber

### Contact

Nathan Voxland (nathan [at] voxland.net)

### Code

Code Consultant is written in Java on Gooogle App Engine.
See [github.com/nvoxland/code-consultant](https://github.com/nvoxland/code-consultant)

Comment: Can your AI pass turing?

Comment: No.  But a lot of times your co-workers can't either...

Comment: Awesome concept. Please consider porting this to IRC... and run an instance on FreeNode.

Comment: I think your bot needs an avatar... maybe something like Bender? http://tiny.cc/bender3

Comment: Is your bot source code available somwhere ?

Comment: The source will hopefully be on http://github.com/nvoxland/code-consultant in the next couple days